# not able to create new flutter project after swutching to dev channel

Tags: dart, flutter

I changed my flutter to dev channel by directly . I downloaded zip file from flutter website extracted and replaced flutter folder at `C:\Program Files\Git`but when trying to create a project it takes forever(never ending). same applies to flutter doctor
`environment path =>C:\Program Files\Git\flutter\bin`

Answer (score 0):

Flutter doesn't work when installed in `C:\Program Files\` because there normal users don't have write permissions.
Either change the permissions for the Flutter install directory, or install it in another directory where your user has write permissions by default.